# Remove Required Validations From Model In C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

This might be very silly question. Still want to clear the doubts......

**I want to update the password in the DB and we are using a common model for signup and update**

ie

```
{
  "email": "string",
  "password": "string",
  "username": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "usertype": "string",
  "professional": "string",
  "securityQuestion": "string",
  "securityAnswer": "string"
}
```

but i dont want  to send evey node from json i want to send only

My endpoint look like this

```
[HttpPatch]
[Route("/forgotpassword")]
public IActionResult ResetPassword( UserCredentialsDto credentials)
{

    if (_authenticationManager.ResetPasword(credentials))
    {
        string success = "Password Has been set succcessfully";
        return Ok(DataWrapperService.WrapData(success, true));
    }
    else {
        string error = "invalid Credentials ";
        return Unauthorized(DataWrapperService.WrapData(error, false));
    }

}

public class UserCredentialsDto
    {

        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Usertype { get; set; }

        public string Professional { get; set; }

        public string SecurityQuestion { get; set; }
        public string SecurityAnswer { get; set; }

    }
```

added the model

Curl Request

```
curl -X 'PATCH' \
  'https://localhost:7038/forgotpassword' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "email": "string",
  "password": "string"
}'
```

**Reposne**

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-b161f3fe7b8c6e10713dab990c1a6928-fabfe562c3c83a8a-00",
  "errors": {
    "Name": [
      "The Name field is required."
    ],
    "Username": [
      "The Username field is required."
    ],
    "Usertype": [
      "The Usertype field is required."
    ],
    "Professional": [
      "The Professional field is required."
    ],
    "SecurityAnswer": [
      "The SecurityAnswer field is required."
    ],
    "SecurityQuestion": [
      "The SecurityQuestion field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help would be helpful I am using .NET 6 and no validation applied over model

Comment: Where are these required validators applied and executed? Please [edit] your post with a [mre].

Comment: no validations are applied @gunr2171. you can use this much and test it

Comment: @SrikrishnaSharma: The result you show is a validation result. Validations _are_ being applied, you just don't seem to know where/how. That will have to be your next step then.

Comment: @Flater created the project from scratch . Could you please where should i check for validation.?

Comment: Does `UserCredentialsDto` have any attributes on the class that you omitted from your example? I'm wondering if there are data validation attributes in a related class, even if there aren't on `UserCredentialsDto`.

Comment: What does `ResetPassword` do? Does it do any database activity? That might be where the validation is happening.

Comment: @AnnL. It doesnot have any attribute over it.

Comment: @SrikrishnaSharma: If I need to tell you how your own project that you built from scratch works, sight unseen, then you've got significantly bigger fish to fry than a validation error.

Comment: @AnnL. But its not even hitting the endpoint Atlease it should hit debug point

Comment: If I were you, I'd do a FindInFiles search (assuming you're using Visual Studio) for "Name" and see how it's handled in other parts of the app. (I'm assuming this error is coming back from the API and isn't being generated on the front end!)

Comment: This is turning into debugging 101, which is _well_ off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @SrikrishnaSharma  If it's not even hitting the endpoint, it's on the client side!  Look at your javascript/angular/whatever!

Comment: @AnnL. I am using postman to hit my api directly and getting this error and only have three classes DTO controller and service layer  and request is not hitting the controller

Comment: So, you're calling the "/forgotpassword" route from Postman, and have debugging going with a breakpoint on the `if` -- and yet the breakpoint isn't ever hit?

Comment: @Flater  As I already told that i have built it from scratch so it have nothing just one controller and service class and check all the code as well  so rather stating so many random points may be true  but if you can provide  exact answer  or method to find error that would be helpful. Also debugging not allowing me to hit on this method 

check middleware program file and no attribute over model

Comment: @AnnL. no debugger is not reaching there

Comment: I'm guessing it's somehow in the default binder, then. Try specifying the `name` property in the JSON, just to see what happens. Does it hit the breakpoint? Does it specify that another field also needs to be specified?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246195/discussion-between-srikrishna-sharma-and-ann-l).

Comment: Also, I know this question may seem insulting, but: you're definitely calling the `localhost` version of your service, on your local machine?

Comment: I will never understand why passwords are stored in a database. Therefore I use Identity Management systems

Comment: @MarkusMeyer Just to inform the  issue is not where the store  the password the issue is updation

Comment: @SrikrishnaSharma I know that the current issue is not about storing passwords. But I'm scared about this solution

Comment: @SrikrishnaSharma : I would like to point out that You are using HttpPatch request and this is not correct way of implementing HttpPatch request. check this [article](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/httpput-or-httppatch-in-asp-net-core-ceaae99e320b) for correctly implementing Patch request.

Answer (score 2):

There're two solutions:

1. Modify the type of the nullable  properties  to "string?"
2. Set as below:

   ```
   builder.Services.AddController(options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);
   ```

You could read the document related:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#non-nullable-reference-types-and-the-required-attribute